# Why can't I use operator% on initializer_list?

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, initializer-list

In algorithms where membership tests are frequent, I really miss the infix ∈ operator, and I like to use the % operator instead.  It works well with the regular containers, but for some reason clang and gcc reject it for initializer_lists.  I have no doubt they are "right" in the sense that the standard is certainly rejecting this.  But why?

```
#include <initializer_list>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

/// Whether e ∈ m.
template <typename T, typename U>
inline bool
in(const U& k, const std::initializer_list<T>& m)
{
  return std::find(begin(m), end(m), k) != std::end(m);
}

/// Whether e ∈ m.
template <typename T, typename U>
inline bool
operator%(const U& k, const std::initializer_list<T>& m)
{
  return in(k, m);
}

/// Whether e ∈ m.
template <typename T, typename U>
inline bool
operator%(const U& k, const std::vector<T>& m)
{
  return in(k, m);
}

int main()
{
  using strings = std::vector<std::string>;
  std::cout << ("foo" % strings{"foo", "bar"}) << std::endl;
  std::cout << in("foo", {"foo", "bar"}) << std::endl;

  std::cout << ("foo" % {"foo", "bar"}) << std::endl;  // fails
}
```

Comment: Rather than `%`, perhaps a [named operator](https://github.com/klmr/named-operator) like `<in>` would be more intuitive?

Comment: I don´t hate operator overloading, but integer modulo and element-of of a set are completely different things. Is it really a problem to use a normal function instead of making confusing operator stuff?

Comment: `template<class T> using il<T>=std::initializer_list<T>;` could help.  `"foo" % il<std::string>{"foo","bar"}`.  This requires mentioning the type.

Comment: @deviantfan Well, that's because you are used to read `%` as only modulo, that's all.  Were you shocked to see bit-shifting used for streams?  Boost already uses `%` for serialization, or for feeding printf-like formats.  Languages have been contained into ASCII for years and played ASCII art to introduce new operators.  Aren't you disturbed by the lambda of Haskell spelled '\'?  Since `∈` is not ASCII, `%` is reasonable, and it is actually the character used in the Claire programming language to denote membership test.

Comment: @chris Well, why not, I supposed you are referring to "Named operators".  In which case, you are referring to tricks played with `operator<` and `operator>`, in which case I'm back to square one: operators don't play with initializer_lists in c++.

Comment: @akim `Were you shocked ...  Aren't you disturbed ...` What´s your problem? And yes, of course I´m used to % as modulo, because that´s what it was in C and C++ since ever. And that´s why. C++ is not Claire or anything, C++ is C++, and people using C++ will expect it to behave like C++. If you like redefining everything, you´ll have a hard time programming in teams, or more generally that other people understand your code.

Comment: @deviantfan Apparently you've been hurt by my words.  I'm sorry about that, it was not my intention.

Comment: @deviantfan `I don´t hate ... Is it really a problem ... instead of making confusing operator stuff`, apparently you don't like people answering the way you speak to them

Answer (score 7):

A *braced-init-list* isn't an expression, and can only appear in certain places. Those places include function arguments, but not the operands of most operators.

In some cases, it can be used to create a temporary `initializer_list`, but it isn't itself an `initializer_list`.

Comment: Or as Scott likes to put it: "Braced initializers have no type … braced initializers have not type … braced initializers have no type … … unless they do!"

Comment: Hi Mike.  Again, I have no doubt that the standard says so.  My question is why?  What difference is there here bw a function call and using an operator?  What did the committee ruled operators out?

Comment: OK, the answer is given here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11445905/1353549.  In short, the problem is that the grammar would then have generate really bad conflicts in LR parsers.