# Multiplying user-defined arrays in C++

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

typedef std::array<int, 2> eval_t;
eval_t operator*(eval_t e1, eval_t e2) { return {e1[0] * e2[0], e1[1] * e2[1]}; }

int main()
{
    eval_t a = {1, 2};
    eval_t b = a * {2, 1};
    std::cout << "b = (" << b[0] << ',' << b[1] << ')' << std::endl;
}
```

GCC refused to compile my multiplication:

```
$ g++ -std=c++11 test.cc 
test.cc: In function ‘int main()’:
test.cc:10:17: error: expected primary-expression before ‘{’ token
  eval_t b = a * {2, 1};
                 ^
```

I was naively hoping that the only possible operator*() taking `eval_t` as left operand, would be the one I defined, and the right operand would be understood as `eval_t`.

Instead, if I write:

```
eval_t a = {1, 2};
eval_t v = {2, 1};
eval_t b = a * v;
```

it works.

Comment: Your operator doesn't even take an `eval_t` to multiply it by, but Clang gives a clear error regardless: *error: initializer list cannot be used on the right hand side of operator '\*'*

Answer (score 3):

`std::array` is an aggregate and it doesn't have a constructor accepting `std::initializer_list` as argument like other containers, so a program can't create an `eval_t` from an `initializer_list`. Thus, the compiler cannot find a matching type of the operator overloaded function, so it failed.

For this reason, `{1, 2}` can't be implicitly converted to an `eval_t` as you expected.

Pure braced-initializers are not allowed with binary operators as per standard, so compiler will reject it. But it is allowed in return statements.  More details are explained in this answer: [Initializer lists and RHS of operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420448/initializer-lists-and-rhs-of-operators)

If you change the statement as follows, it will work

```
eval_t b = a * eval_t{{2, 1}};
```

Comment: The solution is right but the reason is wrong. Braced-initializers are not allowed as operands to operator functions. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420448/initializer-lists-and-rhs-of-operators

Answer (score 2):

Just a syntax error.
Correct the line to these.

```
return{ { e1[0] * e2[0], e1[1] * e2[1] } };
```

and

```
eval_t b = a * eval_t{ { 2, 1 } };
```

Test:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

typedef std::array<int, 2> eval_t;
eval_t operator*(eval_t e1, eval_t e2) 
{
    return{ { e1[0] * e2[0], e1[1] * e2[1] } };
}

int main()
{
    eval_t a = { 1, 2 };
    eval_t b = a * eval_t{ { 2, 1 } };
    std::cout << "b = (" << b[0] << ',' << b[1] << ')' << std::endl;
    // b = (2,2)   

}
```

Comment: Thank you. That works. But are you sure the extra braces are useful?

Comment: Yes. That is the proper syntax for compilers that dont support c++0x. For recent compilers with c++0x, `eval_t {1,2}{}` should do the same job.

Comment: @jafar: if a compiler doesn't support C++11 it won't like the braces for constructors *at all* (or even `std::array`, for what that matters)...

Comment: ok. with `g++ -std=c++11`, it seems that `eval_t{1,2}` is sufficient. and no need for extra braces in the `operator*()`. not sure if it's guaranteed by the standard to work, or if it just happens to work for gcc.

Comment: @MatteoItalia correct!

Comment: @lucasart, Yes, brace elision is a thing.

Answer (score 0):

You might also consider that instead of defining your own overloaded `operator*`, to take advantage of the standard library:

```
std::array<int, 2> a = {1, 2};
std::array<int, 2> b = {2, 1};
std::array<int, 2> c;
std::transform(a.begin(), a.end(), b.begin(), c.begin(), std::multiplies<int>());
```

[**LIVE DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/9fba77c24cd2eed0)

Comment: Yes, that's also possible. Bad taste, though: too verbose and too slow.