# How to overload operator << to work with arrays?

Tags: c++

for something like that

```
class foo
{
    foo& operator<<(const BYTE*){ ...; return *this; };
}

foo f;
f << {0x00, 0x00, 0x00} << {0x00, 0x00, 0x00};
```

`{0x00, 0x00, 0x00}` is not allowed by compiler in such expressions.

Comment: Arrays are not pointers and pointers are not arrays.

Comment: Are you trying to pass a pointer to a temporary? That's bound to result in fun.

Comment: Those are not arrays....

Comment: looks like this is not supported in C++: [Initializer lists and RHS of operators](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420448/initializer-lists-and-rhs-of-operators)