# Compare STL container contents to an initialiser list

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

I want to do something like

```
std::vector<int> foobar()
{
    // Do some calculations and return a vector
}

std::vector<int> a = foobar();
ASSERT(a == {1, 2, 3});
```

is this possible?

Comment: try assert(a == std::vector<int>({1, 2, 3}));

Comment: No, I was trying to give a simplified example but I guess I simplified it too much.

Comment: Give not so simplified example) Maybe there is another solution

Comment: Why was I downvoted?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately you cannot overload `operator==` to accept a `std::initializer_list` as the second argument (this is a language rule).

But you can define any other function to take a const reference to an `initializer_list`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <vector>

template<class Container1, typename Element = typename Container1::value_type>
bool equivalent(const Container1& c1, const std::initializer_list<Element>& c2)
{
    auto ipair = std::mismatch(begin(c1),
                               end(c1),
                               begin(c2),
                               end(c2));
    return ipair.first == end(c1);
}


int main() {
    std::vector<int> x { 0, 1, 2 };
    std::cout << "same? : " << equivalent(x, { 0 , 1 , 2 }) << std::endl;
}
```

expected result:

```
same? : 1
```

Comment: It's a shame you can't overload operators for initializer_list, do you know why that is?

Comment: I cannot think of a good reason for it. Perhaps simply because `std::initializer_list` is a 'special' class which has one design goal - to facilitate constructors of containers from literals? We'd need to ask someone who was involve with the standard for the reason (if indeed there is one).

Comment: I found [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420448/initializer-lists-and-rhs-of-operators): it seems like parsing initialiser lists as the LHS of operators would be too difficult, so operator overloads were disallowed entirely.

Answer (score 3):

Yes:

```
ASSERT(a == std::vector<int>{1,2,3});
```

Comment: I was hoping there was a way to do it without the `std::vector<int>`.

Comment: @dshepherd : Then how do you identify the container? There should be a difference in the output of the assert statement if `a` is a vector of 1,2,3 or an unordered_map containing 1,2,3.

Comment: If ASSERT is a macro, remember to add other parenthesis: `ASSERT((a == std::vector<int>{1, 2, 3}));` or it will not compile.

Comment: @vincentp If this is true, then the implementation of `ASSERT` is wrong. Correctly written macros should not require you to use special syntax to invoke them.

Comment: @therainmaker I wouldn't expect it to allow comparisons with an unordered map, but it could compare to vectors, arrays and sets.

Comment: @dshepherd : I meant unordered_sets in my previous comment. Apologies for that. But my previous point holds. Are you saying you want to implement something like container invariant comparison? That doesn't seem right.

Answer (score 1):

You have explicitly to specify the type of the right hand operand. For example

```
std::vector<int> v = { 1, 2, 3 };
assert( v == std::vector<int>( { 1, 2, 3 } ) );
```

because the `operator ==` is a template function and the compiler is unable to deduce the second operand to the type `std::vector<int>`

Answer (score 1):

The most natural and/or 'prettiest' working implementation that I am aware of, assuming that what you want to do is impossible (as people on this site have said multiple times), is to `typedef` your `vector` type as follows:

```
typedef std::vector<int> vec;

ASSERT(a == vec({1, 2, 3}));
```

... where `vec` is named whatever you want.

If someone knows of something even more natural, please let us know.