# Overload type conversion to initializer list

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, stl

Let's say I am developing a class `Vec<T>`, which represents a mathematical vector with elements of type `T`.

For convenience I created the constructor that takes `std::initializer_list`:

```
Vec(std::initializer_list<T> l)
    : size(l.size())
{
    data = new T[size];
    std::copy(l.begin(), l.end(), data);
}
```

So now I can do the following things:

```
v += Vec<int>({ 1, -1 });
bool equal = (v == Vec<int>({ 8, 9 }));
```

And so on... However, it would be great if I could write it even shorter and cleaner:

```
v += { 1, -1 };
bool equal = v == { 8, 9 };
```

How do I achieve such behavior? I suppose I could overload a type-conversion operator to `std::initializer_list`, but is it even considered normal practice? How bad is it for compilation time and performance, and does it even work?

What about `std::vector`, does it support something like that in C++11?

**EDIT:**

So, here's my `operator+=`:

```
Vec<T> & operator+=(const Vec<T> &v)
{
    assert(size == v.size);
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
        data[i] += v.data[i];
    return *this;
}
```

The answers in the comments are correct, `initializer_list` actually works after assignment operators:

```
v += {2, 3};
v -= {2, 3};
```

I was trying to write something like this:

```
v = v + {2, 3};
```

That's why it didn't work.

So, the conclusion is: you can use it like this after assignment and compound-assignment operators, but for binary arithmetic operators and comparisons it won't work, am I correct? I suppose creating custom literal is not an option either.

By the way, how about:

```
const Vec<float> a{ 1.01, 2.02 };  // error: conversion from 'double' to 'float' requires a narrowing conversion    test_app
const Vec<float> b{ 1.01f, 2.02f };  // works, obviously
```

Can I do something to enable implicit conversion in the first case?

**EDIT2**

Here is the `operator+`:

```
friend Vec<T> operator+(Vec<T> v, const Vec<T> &w)
{
    v += w;  // reuse compound assignment
    return v;  // return the result by value (uses move constructor)
}
```

Comment: Show your `operator+=`. This should already work as you describe.

Comment: `v == { 8, 9 }` is syntactically invalid.

Comment: [`operator+=` just works](http://rextester.com/NBE83364) with no extra effort. I would imagine most other operators would, too. `operator==` is an exception; off the top, I'm not quite sure why it's special here.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Assignment operators are the special ones. Most other operators do not accept braced-init-list as operand.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420448/initializer-lists-and-rhs-of-operators) explains it.

Comment: This question would be less of an arse-ache if it were actually complete. Where's your [MCVE]?

Comment: @cpplearner Right, I've just looked it up. "**[expr.ass]/9** A *braced-init-list* may appear on the right-hand side of [various assignment operators]".

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: And if the asker were actually around to tend to the question...

Comment: @KerrekSB: It's only been up for 30 minutes. Patience!

Comment: Show your `operator+`. This should already work as you describe.

Comment: Re: initializing `Vec<float>` with `initializer_list<double>`. This can be made to work with a templated constructor: `template <typename U> Vec(std::initializer_list<U> l) {...}` (implementation same as in your example). `std::copy` call would fail to compile if `U` is not in fact implicitly convertible to `T`.

Comment: Ah, no, `v + {1, 2}` doesn't work, because the grammar doesn't allow a braced list there. The compound-assignment is special, because it allows an *initializer-clause* for the right-hand operand rather than just an expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, `v + {1, 2}` is not a well-formed expression in C++ for grammatical rules. Most binary operators only take *expressions* for each of the operands, and the braced list is not an expression. The compound assignment operator `+=` is special, because assignment also accepts an *initializer-clause* for the right-hand operand, so `v += {1, 2}` happens to work.

Some alternatives:

```
operator+(v, {1, 2})
v + Vec<int>({1, 2})
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Another option I think is to create functions like `add` or `isEqualTo`, where you can easily pass initializer lists, like this:
`v.isEqualTo({1,2,3});`

Answer (score 1):

How about `v.equals({8, 9})`? Also, while `v + {1, 2, 3, 4}` is not possible, you might still overload the comma operator as many vector-matrix implementations do (not for int, but for a specific type, like: `v + (V(1), 2, 3, 4)`, add macros if you like them).

Comment: Yes, I've chosen to go with methods like your `equals`, see my comment to the accepted answer.
BTW, I've seen comma implementations in a couple of libraries (like OpenCV for example), but I'd rather stay away from this design. Not a particularly obvious interface)