# implicit conversion not performed on overloaded operator+'s arguments?

Tags: c++11

All codes are compiled on g++ 6.4.0 with -std=c++11 option. 
Consider the following:

```
#include<iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;
struct Direction{
    int dx,dy;
};
struct Point{
    int x,y;
    Point operator+(const Direction& d){
        return {x+d.dx,y+d.dy}
    }
};
int g(const Direction& d){
    return d.dx+d.dy;
}
int f(const Point& p){
    return p.x+p.y;
}
int main(){
    cout << g({1,2}) << endl;
    cout << f({1,2}) << endl;
    Point A {1,3};
    cout << f(A+{1,1}) << endl; //line 25
}
```

The compiler complains,

> 25 | error: expected primary-expression before '{' token

When line 25 is removed, the program works well, outputting two `3`s seperated by a `'\n'`.
However, I am a bit puzzled.

As far as my knowledge extends, line 25 should work like this:

> 1. The only `Point::operator+` takes a `const Direction&` as its only argument. Because it can, `{1,1}` is implicitly converted to an object of type `Direction`, just like how `f({1,2})` is evaluated as `f(Point{1,2})`. Though this object is temporary, this shouldn't matter, as the argument is `const`.
> 2. `int f(const Point& p)` takes this temporary "`Point {2,4}`" as an argument and returns a `6`.
> 3. `6` is outputted, followed by an `'\n'`.

But this is not the case.

Do implicit conversions not work for overloaded operators? but we know this is not the case, because the below code certainly works properly, outputting a `98` in my system:

```
#include<iostream>
int main(){
    std::cout << 1 + 'a' << std::endl;
}
```

I also considered the possibility that two implicit conversions in one line is a no-no, but the below code compiles:

```
int main(){ //line 21: continued from the code at the top
    cout << g({1,2}) + f({1,2}) << endl;
}
```

My question is:

**1. Why does line 25 give errors**

**2. and what should I additionally define so that I can preserve the expression in line 25?**

Thank you.

Comment: see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420448/initializer-lists-and-rhs-of-operators