# std::initializer_list as right hand argument for overloaded operator?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, initializer-list

I want to use something like the "in" operator available in other programming languages. I read many posts about that already. But, nothing that fits my needs.

What I wanted to do is a little bit different. Please see the following first example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>
#include <algorithm>

bool operator ==(const int lhs, std::initializer_list<int>& il) {
    return std::find(il.begin(), il.end(), lhs) != il.end();
}
int main() {
    
    std::initializer_list<int> il{1,2,3,4,5};
    std::cout << (3 == il) << '\n';
    
    // std::cout << (3 == {1,2,3,4,5}) << '\n';   // Does not compile
}
```

But this does not compile. Presumably, because an initalizer list is no expression. Although there are exceptions. A `std::initializer_list` maybe a function parameter, although also here expressions are expected.

And since any operator is basically also a function, my hope was, that I also can use `std::initalizer_list` as argument.

But I cannot.

I tried the same approach by defining an own `operator` with a name by misusing overloading of 2 operators. See below:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

// New operator: is_in
enum { is_in };

int operator < (const int& lhs, decltype(is_in)) { return lhs; }
int operator > (int lhs, std::vector<int>& rhs) { return std::find(rhs.begin(), rhs.end(), lhs) != rhs.end();}
int operator > (int lhs, std::initializer_list<int>& rhs) { return std::find(rhs.begin(), rhs.end(), lhs) != rhs.end(); }

int main() {
    std::vector validValues{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

    bool b = (5 <is_in> validValues);

    // bool b = (5 <is_in> { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });  // Does not compile

    std::cout << b << '\n';
}
```

Same principle, same problem . . .

Is there any way to make this happen?

Comment: Related to [initializer-lists-and-rhs-of-operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420448/initializer-lists-and-rhs-of-operators)

Comment: @Jarod42: Thanks. Reading that I have only low to 0 hope for a solution . . .

Comment: Alias to shorten `std::initializer_list` as workaround...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to take the `initializer_list` by `const&`:

```
bool operator==(const int lhs, const std::initializer_list<int>& il)
```

```
std::cout << (3 == std::initializer_list{1,2,3,4,5}) << '\n';
```

For the `is_in` test you could overload the comma operator and do something like this:

```
template<class T>
struct is_in {
    is_in(const std::initializer_list<T>& il) : ref(il) {}
    const std::initializer_list<T>& ref;
};

template<class T>
bool operator,(const T& lhs, const is_in<T>& rhs) {
    return std::find(rhs.ref.begin(), rhs.ref.end(), lhs) != rhs.ref.end();
}

int main() {
    bool b = (5, is_in{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });

    std::cout << b << '\n';
}
```

Comment: Yes, correct, thanks. But I do not want to write ````std::initializer_list{1,2,3,4,5}```` but just ````{1,2,3,4,5}```` . . .

Comment: @ArminMontigny I see. Ok, then this probably doesn't help much then.

Answer (score 4):

Brace init lists are only allowed in certain contexts by exceptions to the grammar. And while an overloaded operator involves a function call, it must still obey the standard grammar rules unless you invoke it by name (`operator@`) in a function call.

So your named operator *can* work, but you must overload one of the operators for which an exception exists<sup>1</sup>. A rough summary of those overloadable operators is:

- Assignment, including compound assignment (`operator=`, `operator +=`).
- Index (`operator[]`).
- Function call (`operator()`).

None of those may be overloaded as a non-member, so getting symmetry (`<is_in>` or `=is_in=`), is not possible. But if forego that, we [can do](https://wandbox.org/permlink/sZ90Q9WAvyKyABd0) something like

```
#include <iostream>
#include <initializer_list>

inline constexpr class op {
    template<typename T>
    friend auto operator< (T const& t, op) {
        struct {
            T const & t;
            bool operator=(std::initializer_list<T> il) {
                return std::find(il.begin(), il.end(), t) != il.end();
            }
        } ret{t};
        return ret;
    }
} is_in;

int main() {

    bool b = (5 <is_in= { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 });

    std::cout << b << '\n';
}
```

Which is not too pretty... I guess we can choose another operator instead of `operator<` to perhaps improve the look of this, but it seems like folly in general. This is already a bit too obscure.

---

<sup>1</sup> - On that front, you should know that overloading operators whose parameters are purely standard types is ill-advised. The standard can change the library definition at any time and break your code gloriously.

Comment: Upped for the explanation. Still, the `is_in= {` is **un-natural** to me.